# Help to choose the answer that fits the context of a paragraph

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> 最終的に私が出版を決断した理由はただ一つ、本書を手に取ってくださった方が、改めて物語の魅力を確認し、物語の役割に目覚め、「ああ、本を
> a. 読めば
> b. 読むことは
> c. 読んでいれば
> d. 読んでいる人は
>
> 何と素晴らしいことであろうか」と思ってくれたら、との願いが
> A. ありました
> B. あったというのです
> C. あったからなのです
> D. あったはずなのです

1. I wonder why the answer is 読むこと. Is 読めば wrong?
2. The answer to the second one is あったからなのです. Is this because との願いが->との=という? Why is あったというのです wrong?

Entire paragraph --

> 最終的に私が出版を決断した理由はただ一つ、本書を手に取ってくださった方が、改めて物語の魅力を確認し、物語の役割に目覚め、「ああ、本を読むことは何と素晴らしいことであろうか」と思ってくれたら、との願いがあったからなのです。
>
> もし他所の星から来た生物が、本を読んでいる人間を見たらどう思うだろう、と私は想像することがあります。小さな箱型の紙の束を手に、ただじっと座っているだけで、あるいは寝転がっているだけで、時折、一枚紙がめくられる以外変化はなく、ただ静かに時間が過ぎてゆく。いくら**辛抱強く**待っていても、何か新しい製品が生み出されるわけでもない。**一体何の得があって人間たちはこんな地味な営みをしているのか**？きっとそんな風に首を傾げるのではないでしょうか。
>
> その時人間の心がどれほど劇的に揺さぶられているか、それは目に見えません。効果を数字によって測ることも不可能です。だからこそ**かけがえがない**のだ、**自分が自分であるための大切な証明になるのだ、ということを、くどいくらいに繰り返し語っているのが、** → refer to what? Reading a book?
> a.本書です
> b.理由です
> c.本書で明らかになります
> d.本書の中で言いたいことです。

1. In the first paragraph the author decides to publish his work(?) and the reason is because he wants people who read his book to think that reading a book is wonderful thing(?)
2. Maybe its about how wonderful is reading a book(?) and its about people who wait next publication of book(?)
   地味な営みをしている->読書=地味？
   The author wondering about 宇宙人 who see people on earth reading book and wondering what's profit people will get by reading a book
3. How exciting something is(?) can neither be seen through eyes nor measured.
   For the last part the answer is 本書です. I thought it was 本書の中で言いたいことです

Answer (score 4):

Both questions seen in the paragraph can have multiple answers grammatically, but only one of each fits the meaning of the entire sentence.

> 「本を**読めば**何と素晴らしいことであろうか」
>   "What a wonderful thing it* is **once** (somebody) reads books!"
>
> 「本を**読むことは**何と素晴らしいことであろうか」
>   "What a wonderful thing read**ing** books is!"
>
> 「本を**読んでいれば**何と素晴らしいことであろうか」
>   "What a wonderful thing it* is **when once / if only** (somebody) **is reading** books!"
>
> ×「本を**読んでいる人は**何と素晴らしいことであろうか」
>   *unacceptable; in Japanese, こと only stands for "deed/event"* thing *as opposed to もの for "object"* thing

<sup>*The *it* doesn't refer to the clause that comes after in translations.</sup>

---

- 最終的に私が出版を決断した**理由**は… "The reason I finally decided to publish it..."

  > …との願いが**ありました**。
  >   "...**has** a wish that is —."
  >
  > …との願いが**あったというのです**。
  >   "...**is allegedly that I had** a wish that is —."
  >
  > …との願いが**あったからです**。
  >   "...**is because I had** a wish that is —."
  >
  > …との願いが**あったはずなのです**。
  >   "...**is that it is supposed to have had** a wish that is —." (??) *(almost unacceptable)*
  >
  > cf.
  >   …との願いです。 "...is a wish that is —."
  >   …との願いがあったのです。 "...is that I had a wish that is —."

You're correct that との is a formal alternative to quotative という, but it has nothing to do here.

> 日本に行きたい（という／との）願い *quotative*
>   マイケル・ジャクソン（という／× との）人 *not quotative*

---

**UPDATE**

> 1. *First paragraph the author decide to publish his work(?) and the reason is because he want people who read his book to think that reading a book is wonderful thing(?)*

You're right. So, this 物語 turns out to generally refer to what we call "story" or "storytelling".

> 2. *Maybe its about how wonderful is reading a book(?) and its about people who wait next publication of book(?)
>
>      地味な営みをしている->読書=地味？？
>
>      The author wondering about 宇宙人 who see people on earth reading book and wondering what's profit ppl will get by reading a book (?)(?)(?)(?)*

The passage is about how reading books would look objectively. The writer brings up an alien as an example who doesn't understand terran people's internal activity. You're correct about `地味な営み = 読書`.

> 3. *How exciting something is(?) cannot be seen through eyes neither measure by number. Dont get the point
>
>      Last part the answer is 本書です
>
>      First i thought that the answer is 本書の中で言いたいことです*

Try understand 数字 as "data". 数字 often represents something can be seen objectively. I personally feel there's a big leap in logic :) but anyway, the writer is arguing that how people's hearts are moved by literature is unmeasurable in objective and physical (~ 目に見える) form, and thus invaluable.

The construction in the last part `Verb のが X だ/です` is a [cleft sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence) that can be rephrased as `X こそが Verb`, that means, *X* must be the subject of the *V*. If you fill in 本書の中で言いたいことです, it'd mean "what I want to tell in this book is telling..." and wouldn't make sense.

> *だからこそ**かけがえがない**のだ、**自分が自分であるための大切な証明になるのだ、ということを、くどいくらいに繰り返し語っているのが、** → refer to what? Reading a book?*

Yes, the subject of かけがえがない and 自分が自分であるための大切な証明になるのだ are reading books.

Comment: Predicate should at least noun? との願いがありました->理由(noun)? This paragraph want to say that the author finally publish his work, and the reason are he want people who read his novel to understand how wonderful is reading book との願いがあったからのです->this explain the author wish?物語 is this refer to real legend story or the book that was written by the author? 本を読めば何と素晴らしいことであろうか」 "What a wonderful thing it is once (somebody) reads books!"->this sentence doesnt fit the meaning of entire paragraph?

Comment: @DevinaMuljono Maybe should I clarify that "it" isn't "once (somebody) reads books"? It's effectively "what a wonderful thing something is once I read books" but sounds incohesive because the "something" isn't referred to anywhere in the passage.

Comment: @DevinaMuljono I have no idea what 物語 really is from this short paragraph, and I believe it doesn't affect the answer.

Comment: can i post the entire paragraph here? Because i really want to know what is the author refer to 物語 in this paragraph

Comment: so あったというのです refer to what we heard from another person? がありましたrefer to condition or characteristic for ex: 象は鼻が長いです(？) the same as 理由=象(i suppose the same structure)？ so thats why this is wrong because 理由isnt the subject (?)

Comment: @DevinaMuljono Yes you can put here, or in the question if you think it's relevant.

Comment: @DevinaMuljono という that ends a sentence becomes "they say" or "you can say". AはBがある always means "A has B", similar structure with 象は鼻が長い, but you can also learn it as an idiom.

Comment: ah okay i hve post the entire paragraph please help me to understand ths paragraph ><

Comment: Nitpick: by 'ungrammatical' you mean 'nonsensical'; each of those alternatives feel grammatical (syntactically correct) to me.

Comment: @oals Maybe I should change it to "unacceptable".

Comment: That should work too.